# How to render Quickbooks Connect button in web app

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I have successfully made an API call from my web app using sandbox information by following [this post](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_sdks/0209_php/0001_quick_start) so I can get the sandbox company info.  Now I need to replace my hard-coded keys with the button to authenticate a user and interact with their account.

**How do I get the [Connect to Quickbooks button](https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2015/09/03/new-connect-to-quickbooks-and-sign-in-with-intuit-buttons) displayed so I can Authorize a user and get the tokens?**

I read this post about [OAuth 2.0 Server Side Web Apps](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/widgets) but I feel stupid because I cannot find anywhere about getting the widget on the actual page for the user to click and set up our OAuth process.

Here is it working when I have the keys hardcoded from sandbox, just dont know how to get the Connect button so I can change these to grab the returned keys

```
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
           'auth_mode' => 'oauth1',
             'consumerKey' => "erferg2342r",
             'consumerSecret' => "egsergrh3242334t343",
             'accessTokenKey' => "fbsfsxfg232342342",
             'accessTokenSecret' => "srgserg53544",
             'QBORealmID' => "123145856777424",
             'baseUrl' => "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/"
        ));

        $CompanyInfo = $dataService->getCompanyInfo();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($CompanyInfo);
        echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating this form directly.  Instead you will open a browser control and navigate to a specific page for authorization. You need to handle the browser control's navigate event to catch the response with the authorization codes.  I suggest you find a sample app and hook it to your sandbox.  It will cover many questions you haven't gotten to yet.  :)